how do you change vscode settings based off of selected colourscheme
I know you can override settings based off of language with the following syntax
"[rust]": {
    // ...
},

but i was wondering if theres any way to do this based off of the selected colourscheme, things like erorr lens extension or vim extension make you use fixed colour settings which is fine if you use only one theme, but i switch between light and dark themes, so i would like to have them use different colours based off of the different colourscheme that is selected which would need changing the settings based off of the selected colourscheme
"vim.highlightedyank.color": "#ffffff05",
"vim.highlightedyank.textColor": "#ff9e64", // orange 

"todo-tree.highlights.customHighlight": {
    "BUG": {
        "icon": "bug",
        "background": "#cb4d4d2f",
        "gutterIcon": true,
        "foreground": "#dd5353",
        "iconColour": "#dd5353",
        "borderRadius": "2.5pt",
    },
    "FIXME": {
        // "icon": "flame",
        "icon": "tools",
        "background": "#fecc7d2a",
        "gutterIcon": true,
        "foreground": "#d8ae6b",
        "iconColour": "#d8ae6b",
        "borderRadius": "2.5pt",
    },
    "TODO": {
        "background": "#55bb9c2d",
        "gutterIcon": true,
        "foreground": "#55bb9c",
        "iconColour": "#55bb9c",
        "icon": "tasklist",
        "borderRadius": "2.5pt"
    },
}

i tried doing something like this
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Tokyo Night]": {
        "vim.highlightedyank.color": "#ffffff05",
        "vim.highlightedyank.textColor": "#ff9e64", // orange 
    },
}

but workbench.colorCustomizations only allows for theme change settings, extension settings cannot be tweaked like that

let the vim extension define color names in the package.json and then you can use workbench.colorCustomizations and modify these custom color names by theme
